# Run Command on Virtual Machine failing & preventing other 'Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand'

Tags: azure, azure-automation

**Problem:** When I run a Powershell runbook with an 'Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand' on an Azure Windows VM, and I have to STOP the runbook because of an error in the invoked command (and it idles forever), all new repetitions of the runbook fail with **"Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command."**.

This is the runbook statement to have a PS script running on the VM:

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $objVM.ResourceGroupName -Name $objVM.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $strRemoteScriptFileNameTmp -Parameter $hshParams
```

The PS code in '$strRemoteScriptFileNameTmp' has this statement in it, which makes the runbook idling, ,i.e. need to be fixed:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "$strRunTimeEnv $strExecPath $strExecParaString"
```

The -Command then looks as this; it shall install that ODBC driver to the VM, and works when executed with the PS CLI of the VM (RDP'd):

```
msiexec.exe /quiet /passive /qn /norestart /l* D:\msodbcsql_13.0_x64.log /package D:\UpdateODBC\Application\Live\msodbcsql_13.0_x64.msi IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES ADDLOCAL=ALL
```

**Question:** I know there is a timeout of 90 minutes for that (orphaned) command of the runbook. But, where is this idling, on the VM or the Automation Account? And, how can I kill it? It seems ridiculous to wait for 90 minutes before a new attempt to run the runbook can be made.

(I am not exactly get into a productive workflow here the way Msft have set this up... And yes, I read the posts on this topic already, and also the Msft docs which really need proof-reading by an English speaker, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

To conclude this I just like to share what I was given by MSDN in their answer:

"...Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand is actually using a REST command to send a powershell script to the VM..."

"There are restrictions on what can be done via this method:

- One script at a time can run.
- You can't cancel a running script.
- The maximum time a script can run is 90 minutes. After that, it will time out.
  "

See:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#restrictions][1]

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released a newer version of **Invoke-AzVMRunCommand** called **[Set-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command-managed)**, which adds some functionality that will allow it to circumvent this issue:

- Parallel execution of multiple scripts
- Includes **Remove-AzVMRunCommand**, which can be used to terminate script execution of in-progress scripts